# C# to add test case or user story under a team in a project

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops, team-explorer

I wanted to access TFS project using C# and create a test case. below is the project structure

**URL : http://localhost:8080/tfs/test**

**Project : project1**

**Team Name : team1**

Add test case or work item here

i am able to connect to project and add a work item over there, but how can i connect to a particular team in project  ( in this case it is team1 ) and add a test case or work item

here is my sample code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri collectionUri = (args.Length < 1) ?
                     new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs/test") : new Uri(args[0]);
        System.Console.WriteLine(collectionUri);
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["project1"];
        WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["User Story"];


        // Create the work item. 
        WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
        {
            // The title is generally the only required field that doesn’t have a default value. 
            // You must set it, or you can’t save the work item. If you’re working with another
            // type of work item, there may be other fields that you’ll have to set.
            Title = "test through code",
            Description =
                "this is an automation user story genrated"
        };

        // Save the new user story. 
        userStory.Save();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the Classification fields (Area and Iteration) to define "teams" in TFS.  You didn't specify how you define your "teams" but assuming you use the Classification fields you can set the Iteration field as follows:

```
    WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
    {
        // The title is generally the only required field that doesn’t have a default value. 
        // You must set it, or you can’t save the work item. If you’re working with another
        // type of work item, there may be other fields that you’ll have to set.
        Title = "test through code",
        Description =
            "this is an automation user story genrated",
        IterationPath = FormatPath(commonservice.GetNode(newIterationPath).Path, "Iteration", "MyTeamProject");
    };
```